# ssh into two different machines on same network

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a ssh-enabled machine on my home wifi that I am able to ssh into. I recently got the Linux Subsystem for Windows and I want to ***remotely*** ssh into that as well. Both machines have an static ip assigned from my router, but ssh communicates over port 22. 1st question: How does ssh determine which machine I want to access and, 2nd question: How to specify which machine I want to ssh to?

I know putty works in general, which is fine, but I'm probably a little confused as to how ssh works and how it separates different machines on the same network...

Thanks!

Comment: Different machines -> different IPs. Think of a computer's IP Address as a house address. The port would be which door or window to enter.
But if you mean remotely as in outside your home network, you will need a much deeper understanding of networking to properly configure your router to allow remote connections.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to network engineering.

Comment: @Deathgrip No. Different machines on the same home LAN almost certainly have the same public IP address. From outside the local network, you will use **the same IP address** to connect to an ssh server on either machine. The difference will be which port you use (and how port forwarding is set up).

Comment: @DeNovo Re-read my answer. I called out connecting from outside the home network as an exception. To me "remotely" meant from another host on the network. Obvious why the question was closed citing that it needed to be more focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state in your question, each machine has an IP assigned by the router. That's the address SSH is connecting to. 22 is the default SSH port, but this can be changed within the machine running the server (receiving connections). And the pair IP:port is the full address that needs to be supplied to the SSH client (SSH program that connects to the server).

You should connect to the machine not the router. The router has its own IP. You'd use it to redirect the traffic from outside that router's subnet. In that case you need two different forwards. For example 22 redirecting to Linux's 22 and 2222 forwarding to Windows' 22.

Comment: Ok cool. Also, I'm trying to remotely ssh into these machines. The way I'm currently doing that is sshing into my router in Port 22 which forwards me to my current machine on my network. If I want to add another device on the same network, I need to change the port that ssh gets to on that machine?

Comment: @pianoman102 See my updated answer (second paragraph).

Comment: Gotcha. I think that's what I'm looking for. Do i have to configure the windows side to receive that? Or just do the command differently? For example, ssh username@ip:port?

Comment: @pianoman102 You need an SSH server running on Windows. In server's configuration the port is defined. Then if necessary set the port forwarding in the router. That's all.

Comment: Awesome. And it would need to forward to port 2222, yeah?

Comment: @pianoman102 Once the server is up, it's listening on whatever port the config says. Say, it's 22. Now you SSH into Windows from within LAN at Win-IP:22. (I'm leaving any firewall issues aside.) But to get to this machine from outside the LAN, there needs to be a redirection on the router. Any port number is valid, as long as it's not used by something else.

Comment: @pianoman102 Also I'm not suggesting in any way that you can reach your router from outside your LAN. If it's a home router, you most likely can't reach it from outside your home (LAN). But that's another story.

Comment: As far as the public IP (which is what is relevant here, since the OP would like to connect from outside the local network), it is very unlikely that the machine has a different public IP from the router, or any other machine on the same LAN. The router, your phone, your TV, tablet, laptop, ANYTHING on a home network almost certainly all have the same public IP address. They have different local IP addresses, sure, but that's not relevant to this question.